# Android Emulator Error, Console error log repeating errors

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I make emulator API level 17 Android 4.2.2, ARM cpu, RAM 512, SD card 200 VM heap=16
Internal Storage 200
when i run emulator its gives errors in errors log in a loop like this

[image]

I don't is that my emulator problem or what I have Eclipe Juno,
**My PC specification are Intel core2duo, ram 2GB, 320 hard disc. Please suggest a solution or a good emulator according to my system specifications...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What CPU\ABI are you using ?
Try using the intel ATOM x86 system image,
you can get it from within the eclipse menus

Window > SDK Manager > Android 4.2.2 (API 17) > Intel x86 Atom system image.

Comment: its somehow working loop of erros has removed emulator is now loading... please suggest me a light emulator which loads quickly...

Comment: That's the reason fans created  a site at ihateeclipse.com - and believe it or not, using the intel Atom is actually concidered fast. Make sure you keep the emulator ON, don't close it and re-run every time you compile...

Comment: thanks emulator is not giving any more error it is still loading after 15 minutes i tried to install HAXM intel hardware accelerator manager but its not installing giving error at installations?? is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try a different emulator, you could use Genymotion (http://www.genymotion.com/). It'll show up as an actual android device in Eclipse, and runs much faster than the one in Eclipse.

<s>While I haven't used it personally, since I test on my physical devices, a lot of people in my mobile development class use it and like it much better.</s>
I have downloaded Genymotion and tried it out, it's very easy to install, configure, and integrate with Eclipse. It is much faster than the emulator included with Eclipse.

Comment: Genymotion does not work i waste a complete day on it,,,

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but Genymotion works fine. I just downloaded and installed it and its Eclipse plugin, and was able to run apps on the Genymotion virtual device from Eclipse without any problems. In other words, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: do you have any tutorials about genymotion because its connection is does not established with its virutal machines..

Comment: Look at https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/. Especially https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#collapse8. Make sure you installed the Eclipse plugin, because all I had to do was install, set up a virtual device, install the plugin and Eclipse was able to use it without any problems